# Adding numbers together from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read in integers from a file, then display them and add them together and then display the total. My code is not working however, `sum += scan.nextInt();` is causing errors. Can someone please help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
public class HandlingExceptions {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int sum = 0;

    File numbersFile = new File("numbers.txt");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(numbersFile);

    while(scan.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
        sum += scan.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(sum);

    scan.close();
    }

}
```

The console shows the following at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at HandlingExceptions.main(HandlingExceptions.java:20)
```

Comment: Edited the question to answer this.

Comment: You call nextInt() twice in your loop  - when you get to the last element, you print it out, but then there are non left when you call nextInt again. Instead, if you want to print it out, you should take a copy of the integer, print it and then add it.

Answer (score 2):

This code is problematic as you are consuming one number to print and other to add. Another problem would be if you had odd numbers in the scanner then you would run into [NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)

```
while(scan.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
    sum += scan.nextInt();
}
```

Change it to :

```
while(scan.hasNextInt()){
    int tempInt = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(tempInt);
    sum += tempInt;
}
```